# Clarification about Timezone Conversion in DateTime

Tags: soql, datetime, timezone

There are lots of posts regarding `DateTime` format. But there are things for which I still can't find a solid answer.

1. I Noticed that `Datetime` field values are converted into UTC and that converted values are kept in the back-end. When rendering those values in the UI, they will be converted back into the Organization/User's timezone.
2. Is it only the values which are coming directly from the UI (user entered) that are converted or it is any `Datetime` field values (such as the ones updated through controllers or triggers) that are converted?
3. In a `SOQL WHERE` clauses, what is the best way to use `DateTime` fields to avoid potential confusing search results?

I recently noticed this behavior in Salesforce and managed to resolve the difficulties. But I really need to get a clear understanding of the ins-and-outs as a developer :).
Below are the assumptions for each of the aboves that I have taken based on my understanding up until now.

1. Yes.
2. All the fields will be converted. No matter if the value has been set by `DateTime.parse(string)` or `DateTime.valueof(string)` or whatever.
3. Hope `DATE_TIME_FORMAULA(convertTimeZone(*dateTime*)) = myValue` will help here. Until now I've been able to manage with `Date` fields since there was no need to filter based on time.

**UPDATE**
When retrieving data via a REST web service does this conversion also happen?

Comment: On your item 3) I thnk it agrees with my colleagues blog post on the subject - see http://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @KeithC Really it's very difficult to implement without knowing what I'm using.

Comment: Does this help ? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/day-light-saving-dst-in-salesforce/4480#4480

Comment: @techtrekker Definitely it helps for get an clear idea about DST with salesforce.

Answer (score 9):

As a baseline Salesforce.com stores all data in the service as UTC.

There are a couple of ways to get to data ..

1. REST API - When you use the REST API Salesforce returns UTC
2. SOAP API- When you use the SOAP API Salesforce returns UTC
3. Standard (OOTB) Page - When you use the standard UI salesforceconverts to the users time zone
4. VisualForce Page - You do the work in Apex Code.

In code you can run in the system context or the user context depending on where you run.  If you run in a system context it is always GMT.  If you run as a user context you can then use the user timezone in the data you received.

[APEX Code Online help for DateTime](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_datetime.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) 
    date() Returns the Date component of a Datetime in the local time zone of the context user.

- dateGMT() Return the Date component of a Datetime in the GMT time
  zone.
- day() Returns the day-of-month component of a Datetime in the local time zone of the context user.
- dayGmt() Returns the day-of-month component of a Datetime in the GMT time zone.
- dayOfYear() Returns the day-of-year component of a Datetime in the local time zone of the context user.
- dayOfYearGmt() Returns the day-of-year component of a Datetime in the GMT time zone.

There are some tools to help in your SOQL Code ... So you can get the datetime in the API users Timezone.  [Here is an example from the SOQL Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

```
SELECT HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)), SUM(Amount)
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))
```